# Can you define a subclass of an abstract class without defining any of the abstract methods defined in the superclass? Why?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, subclass, superclass

For example, if I make an abstract class and it has two abstract methods in it, does my subclass need to have them in some shape or form?
Do i need to include them in like just define them or do i also need to implement them and use them?

Comment: Are you trying to define an abstract subclass, or a concrete subclass?

Comment: You can, but the subclass can’t be concrete until all the abstract methods are overridden and implemented.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your methods in your **abstract class** and so they wont need to be necessary implemented in your **subclass**. Be sure to remove the **abstract keyword** from the **methods** and add body to them (in the abstract class).

You can still override them in your subclass if you want.

- Create a new class file **AnimalTest.java** and paste the code below:

  > ```
  > public class AnimalTest
  > {
  >
  >     public static void main(String[] args)
  >     {
  >         Animal cat = new Cat("pussy");
  >         Animal dog = new Dog("pluto");
  >
  >         cat.speak();
  >         dog.speak();
  >     }
  >
  > }
  >
  > abstract class Animal
  > {
  >
  >     private final String name;
  >     private final String kind;
  >
  >     public Animal(String name, String kind)
  >     {
  >         this.name = name;
  >         this.kind = kind;
  >     }
  >
  >     // It has no body. It contains the abstract keyword. It needs to be implemented in subclass
  >     public abstract void speak(); 
  >
  >     // it's already implemented here, in abstract class. You won't be forced to implement this in subclass. But you can still override it if you want.
  >     public String name()
  >     {
  >         return this.kind + " " + this.name;
  >     }
  > }
  >
  > class Dog extends Animal
  > {
  >
  >     public Dog(String name)
  >     {
  >         super(name, "dog");
  >     }
  >
  >     @Override
  >     public void speak()
  >     {
  >         System.out.println(this.name() + " says woof");
  >     }
  >
  > }
  >
  > class Cat extends Animal
  > {
  >
  >     public Cat(String name)
  >     {
  >         super(name, "cat");
  >     }
  >
  >     @Override
  >     public void speak()
  >     {
  >         System.out.println(this.name() + " says niar");
  >     }
  > }
  > ```

> Result:
>   cat pussy says niar
>   dog pluto says woof

Answer (score 1):

If your subclass is also abstract (`public abstract class MyAbstractClass extends TheOriginalClass`), you don't have to implement any of the methods. Essentially, you could leave the abstract subclass empty.

If your subclass is concrete (`public class MyClass extends TheOriginalClass`), you'll need to implement all the methods.

Regarding "...and use them" in your question: Does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class A {
    abstract void f1();
    abstract void f2();
}

class B extends A {} // won't compile
```

You cannot write a concrete subclass which doesn't implement the abstract methods the compiler will "scream at you". You can define another abstract class and use it as the subclass without needing to implement those methods, however eventually you will find yourself creating a concrete subclass and at that exact point you must implement all the abstract methods, as they are a sort of contract that must be fulfilled.

As to why, well it forces certain design decisions onto you the coder, which seem logical, for example let's say you're making a game and you have many different types of enemies in mind for the game, you'll have a common super-class for all of them, `class Monster` and every behavior that is similar you'll put inside that super class and since you don't know how a Monster moves for example you will mark that method/behavior as abstract and a good reason why would be because you want to force everyone that is working with you on the game to implement that behavior when they are designing their concrete monster, hope the example helped illustrate it a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

> Do i need to include them in like just define them or do i also need to implement them and use them?

Java does not contemplate forward declarations, because everything about the class **must** be implemented within the class. You can define a method without implementing it, but the compiler will force you to mark it as `abstract`. 
You don’t need to **use** them, but it must be implemented anyway. Abstract methods are usually used to be called by superclasses, but nobody forces nobody to call a method in general.

> if I make an abstract class and it has two abstract methods in it, does my subclass need to have them in some shape or form?

If you have an `abstract` class this means that the class has a number of abstract methods that is non-zero.

If you subclass an `abstract` class you’re forced to mark it as `abstract` unless this class implements all the abstract methods.

Does this class have any utility itself other than providing a unified interface for its subclasses? Yes, maybe `static` methods.

But obviously you can’t instantiate an object of a class which has left some methods uninplemented.